# androidx ViewModel MutableLiveData LiveData

Tags: android, kotlin, viewmodel, androidx

I am new to Kotlin and Android programming. I cannot figure out why onChanged didnt show up in the first two examples but the last sample is ok. Any suggestions will be greater appreciated.

```
var liveDataTest:MutableLiveData<String> = MutableLiveData("ABC")
liveDataTest.observe(this, androidx.lifecycle.Observer() {
 //Cannot find "override fun onChanged"
})
```

```
var liveDataTest:LiveData<String> = MutableLiveData("ABC")
liveDataTest.observe(this, androidx.lifecycle.Observer() {
 //Cannot find "override fun onChanged"
})
```

```
class test:androidx.lifecycle.Observer<String>{
    override fun onChanged(t: String?) {
        TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In kotlin user can directly observe without implement override methods :

```
val liveDataTest: MutableLiveData<String> = MutableLiveData("ABC")
        liveDataTest.observe(this, androidx.lifecycle.Observer { it ->
            Toast.makeText(context,it,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is wrong in the first two. If you want to pass an anonymous class like that, the syntax is to use the `object` keyword, and since Observer is an interface, not a class, you don't need to call its constructor with the `()`.

```
liveDataTest.observe(this, object: androidx.lifecycle.Observer {
    override fun onChanged(t: String?) {
        TODO("not implemented")
    }
})
```

But since this is single function Java-defined interface, you can simplify the syntax using a lambda:

```
liveDataTest.observe(this) {
    TODO("not implemented")
}
```